# Dropdown menu does not stay selected when I go back to the page

Tags: php, html

Any idea about, why the drop down menu for the following script would not stay on the selected value:

```
 if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
     $frequency = $_POST['frequency'];
     $fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

     $lines = file($fileName);

     $lines[0]="Center_frequency= ". $frequency."\n";

     file_put_contents($fileName, implode($lines));

 } else {

     $fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

     $lines = file($fileName);

     $frequency=explode(" ",$lines[0]);
     $frequency=$frequency[1];
 }
 ?>
```

but if I put my number in  a quotation mark meaning

```
 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
     $frequency = $_POST['frequency'];
     $fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

     $lines = file($fileName);

     $lines[0]="Center_frequency= ".'"'. $frequency.'"'."\n";

     file_put_contents($fileName, implode($lines));

 } else {

     $fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

     $lines = file($fileName);

     $frequency=explode("\"",$lines[0]);
     $frequency=$frequency[1];
 }
 ?>
```

It would work like a charm meaning the selected value would stay and the drop down menu would not go to the first value on the list.
Here is the html code for the drop down menu

```
     <form action="test.php" name="Calculation" method="post">
     Center Frequency: 
     <select name="frequency" >

     <?php $attr= 'selected="selected"'; ?>

    <option value="4.463" <?php echo $frequency  == '4.463' ? $attr :  ''; ?>>4.463</option>
    <option value="5.2625" <?php echo $frequency  == '5.2625' ? $attr : ''; ?>>5.2625 </option>
    <option value="9.33"   <?php echo $frequency  == '9.33' ? $attr : ''; ?>>9.33 </option>
    <option value="13.5"   <?php echo $frequency  == '13.5' ? $attr : ''; ?>>13.5 </option>
    <option value="16.15"  <?php echo $frequency  == '16.15' ? $attr : ''; ?>>16.15 </option>
    <option value="24.525" <?php echo $frequency  == '24.525' ? $attr : ''; ?>>24.525</option>
    <option value="26.275" <?php echo $frequency  == '26.275' ? $attr : ''; ?>>26.275</option>

   </select>

    <Input Type = "Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value = "Save Parameters">

    </form>
```

Comment: `4.463` is a floating point number, while `'4.463'` is a STRING that happens to contain something that LOOKS like a number. FP comparisons can be very hairy, especially you're doing `float == string` testing.

Comment: Thank you, so you think I should define the variable as a floating point number in my script?

Comment: no. stick with strings. html is inherently a text-based format, so deal with textual "numbers" while in html-land.

Comment: But I am copying the $frequency in a text file that is read by another programm and I can not have quotation marks around my numbers. Now it gives me "4.463" in the text file. I need to see 4.463

Comment: what if you escape the quotation marks?

Comment: That is a great idea, I am going to try it now.

Comment: if you literally have `4.463` in a text file, then it's NOT a floating point number, and the quotes aren't necessary. FP numbers are a binary construct, and would look like binary garbage if you loaded that "text" into an editor.

Comment: So how come the programm see the codes differently. Maybe there is something wrong with my explode function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

        $lines = file($fileName);

        $frequency=explode(" ",$lines[0]);
        $frequency=$frequency[1];

        var_dump($frequency);
        //string(5) "13.5 " <== space
```

**solution**

```
$fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

        $lines = file($fileName);

        $frequency=explode(" ",$lines[0]);
        $frequency=trim($frequency[1]); //trim function
```

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your explode function, this problem is that your $frequency is returning a string with an extra white-space on the right. try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
     $frequency = $_POST['frequency'];
     $fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

     $lines = file($fileName);

     $lines[0]="Center_frequency= ". $frequency."\n";

     file_put_contents($fileName, implode($lines));

 } else {

     $fileName = 'ConfigurationFile.txt';

     $lines = file($fileName);

     $frequency=explode(" ",$lines[0]);
     $frequency=trim($frequency[1]);
 }
```

?>

and it should work